# CakePHP 2 Pagination woes

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.1

I am having a problem getting the precise URL needed when using pagination in CakePHP 2.1.3 which needs to be the same as my custom route. Here is an example of what I have:

**URL:** `/courses/section-name/cat-name/subcat-name`

**My route:**

```
Router::connect('/courses/:section/:cat/:subcat/*', array(
    'controller' => 'courses', 'action' => 'courseCategory'), array(
        'pass' => array('section', 'cat', 'subcat'),
        'section' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
        'cat' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
        'subcat' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'        
    ));
```

Everything works fine in terms of normal navigation using this format and when visiting a page I get paginated results okay with all my links etc. I have set my Paginator Helper 'options' as follows:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url'=>$this->passedArgs));
```

This however produces a URL like eg: `/courses/courseCategory/section-name/cat-name/subcat-name/page:2` which does not work.

If I manually remove the action name '**courseCategory**' from the URL eg: `/courses/section-name/cat-name/subcat-name/page:2` etc, then everything works fine and I go to the relevant page of results, so I guess I am close? However, after many hours of searching, reading the docs/API and trying different things I just cannot get my URL links to appear without the controller's action and it's now driving me mad!

So, I guess the question is either where am I going wrong or does anybody have an alternative solution to this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated & happy to provide more info if needed.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you remove the custom route, does everything work? (aside from the URL being different, obviously). If so, you've narrowed your problem down to your route definition.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. Did you ever find an answer?